# Ubuntu boot time slow than windows

Tags: boot

[image][image]I'm using Asus FX503 laptop
Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8
8GB Ram, 4gb Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 graphics card, 
I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my laptop(not as dual boot), 
I'ts taking nearly 30 seconds to boot after a fresh install, while it took only 15 seconds to boot, when I was using Windows 10.
I know, 30 seconds is not bad, but I was hoping that the boot time would be faster in Ubuntu.
Is there anything, that I can do to decrease the boot time in Ubuntu?

These are the systemd outputs:

```
user@user-FX503VD:~$ systemd-analyze
```

Startup finished in 3.473s (kernel) + 23.594s (userspace) = 27.067s
graphical.target reached after 23.587s in userspace

```
user@user-FX503VD:~$ systemd-analyze blame
     14.555s dev-sda2.device
      8.576s snap-core18-782.mount
      8.376s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-57.mount
      4.661s vmware-USBArbitrator.service
      4.564s snapd.service
      4.296s NetworkManager.service
      3.112s networkd-dispatcher.service
      3.054s udisks2.service
      2.464s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      2.376s dev-loop12.device
      2.160s dev-loop14.device
      2.138s ModemManager.service
      2.115s dev-loop6.device
      2.086s dev-loop22.device
      2.048s dev-loop4.device
      1.993s dev-loop13.device
      1.988s dev-loop15.device
      1.946s grub-common.service
      1.880s dev-loop18.device
      1.739s systemd-sysctl.service
      1.711s thermald.service
      1.673s avahi-daemon.service
      1.398s networking.service
      1.391s keyboard-setup.service
      1.316s gpu-manager.service
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It's unclear (at least to me) whether we are comparing apples to oranges. Did you arrive at your Windows start times with Fast Startup enabled (effectively just waking up from hibernation)? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: No @Elder Geek,  it was not in hibernation. Windows boot time was faster in the beginning. (although it did became slow later, that's one of the reasons, I switched to Ubuntu).

Comment: Have you [checked SMART status](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/528077#528077) on your `/dev/sda` drive to rule out impending drive failure as a cause?

Comment: I've added the screenshots of the SMART assessment, and the current "systemd-analyze" output

Comment: Just a thought. Replacing the hard drive in your laptop with a Solid State drive would decrease your `14.555s dev-sda2.device` time.